# html.twig Form function

Tags: html, twig

I want to add checkPasswordMatch() through JavaScript function in our twig file for 1st nd 2nd Password match in registration form.

Simple HTML FORM this is working but in Twig Form this not working.
In simple form I add like this: -

```
<div">
  <input type="password" id="txtNewPassword" />
</div>
<div>
  <input type="password" id="txtConfirmPassword" onKeyUp="checkPasswordMatch();" />
</div>
```

This is working fine.

And Java Script :-

```
<script>
  function checkPasswordMatch() {
   var password = $("#txtNewPassword").val();
   var confirmPassword = $("#txtConfirmPassword").val();
   alert(password);
   if (password != confirmPassword)
    $("#divCheckPasswordMatch").html("Passwords do not match!");
   else
    $("#divCheckPasswordMatch").html("Passwords match.");
 }
</script>
```

And this is my Twig File where I want to this functionality add :-

```
<label for="username"><strong>Password</strong>
{{ form_widget(form.plainPassword.first,{'id':'txtNewPassword' }) }}
</label>
<label for="username"><strong>Confirm Password</strong>
{{ form_widget(form.plainPassword.second,{'id':'txtConfirmPassword', 'onKeyUp'  :'checkPasswordMatch()' }) }}
</label>
```

Any one know that how I can add this onKeyUp function in this type twig form ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
  $("#txtNewPassword, $txtConfirmPassword").on(function(event) {
    var matchMsg = $("#txtNewPassword").val() == $("#txtConfirmPassword").val() 
                   ? 'Passwords match.'
                   : 'Passwords do not match';
    $("#divCheckPasswordMatch").html(matchMsg);
  });
```

You shouldn't really bind the JS functionality in the twig templates, but in your javascripts.
The code isn't tested on all parts, but should show you the idea.

If this code seems weird, check http://api.jquery.com/on/ to understand javascript events and binding better.

Comment: I could not care less about good or bad practices. In my book, using JQuery is the worst practice ever. To each his own. Nevertheless, I agree it would be more convenient to setup the field checker event handler from JavaScript, to gather all relevant code in one place and become independent of the way the actual form is generated.

Comment: Thanks Marcus. I do'not want to bind the JS functionality in the twig templates. In here only for example. But My problem is solved I was doing wrong in  this part : -{{ form_widget(form.plainPassword.second,{'id':'txtConfirmPassword', 'onKeyUp'  :'checkPasswordMatch()' }) }}. I can remove this and add new {{ form_widget(form.plainPassword.second, { 'attr': {'id': 'txtConfirmPassword', 'onKeyUp':'checkPasswordMatch()'} }) }} . then this is working fine.